# Which bike's best fit for me?

Tags: product-rec

I'm sorry if this isn't the right place for these kinds of questions, but I don't know where else to ask. I haven't owned a bike since I was a kid. I'm planning to buy one and as of now I've narrowed down to these options:

Scott Spark 2012 (used, has some imperfections, nothing serious);
Trek Marlin 5 2020 (new); These two same price.
There's also Scott Sub Speed 20 (This one's a bit cheaper); But I fear this won't handle off-road that well.

I'm mainly looking for a bike which can ride comfortably in city and in off-roads too (there's a forest near where I live). I'm going to be cycling around 20 km per day to University. So my question is are these options good? And how big of a difference is between Spark and Marlin? Is it worth it to buy an used one?

Comment: The problem is that for these kinds of questions the information quickly becomes obsolete and that different people have different personal opinions about various products. It is better to ask about more general properties of bike you would like. You did not even write how do those bikes differ. I do not even know what category of bikes are they: road, mtb, bmx, stunt...

Comment: Also, just the fact you plan to ride in a forest does not give enough information. There are forest trails and forest trails. There are some that can be ridden on a road bike, others are difficult downhills and may be too much for many mountain bikes.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't give enough information. The thing is, I don't really understand differences between the bikes myself, that's why I asked here. I plan to use bike mostly for the city roads, but I also want it to handle rough terrain, cause I plan on taking it in the countryside. The thing is, I wanted to know whether, Scott Spark was better in every way to Trek's Marlin. Or are there aspects in which Marlin beats Spark. I am mainly judging by the price point, cause I don't really understand which parts are considered higher quality. And so wanted some input.

Comment: To clarify, mentioned bikes are from very different price points. However, one's used and one's new, so they're sold at same price. I was wondering what were real differences in usability. From what I've seen Spark's been mostly used for trails, so I don't know how it will handle city roads. And there has to be a reason why one bike's so much pricier than the other one, so I was wondering if these reasons correlate with my needs.. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Check if they have eyelets for a rack. It is the single most useful thing that can discriminate between them, to understand if they are a good fit to be a commuting bike.

I would then say Scott sub speed 20. With the saved money you can buy a very good lock and some tyres with a grippy thread, but not too wide (if yours has mudguards).

Answer (score 0):

The single most important criterion (especially for a guy) is "stand-over height", the height of the top bar relative to the height of your crotch.  For a standard diamond frame there should be 2-4 inches.

After that, "reach" (how far forward the handlebar is) is probably the second most important issue, but this depends on your physical condition and several other factors.

You basically have to ride the bike (or one very much similar to it) to tell if it's a good "fit" or not.

Comment: That won't be too useful with the MTB bikes mentioned (I made a search since my comments. I understand the question is not about the fit but about fitness for purpose.